# Teacher force training PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to do a seq2seq prediction. For this, I have a LSTM layer followed by a fully connected layer. I employ Teacher training during the training phase and would like to skip this (I maybe wrong here) during testing phase. I have not found a direct way of doing this so I have taken the approach shown below.

```
def forward(self, inputs, future=0, teacher_force_ratio=0.2, target=None):
    outputs = []
    for idx in range(future):
        rnn_out, _ = self.rnn(inputs)
        output = self.fc1(rnn_out)
        if self.teacher_training:
            new_input = output if np.random.random() >= teacher_force_ratio else target[idx]
        else:
            new_input = output
        inputs = new_input
```

I use a `bool` variable `teacher_training` to check if Teacher training is needed or not. Is this correct? If yes, is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PyTorch all classes that extend `nn.Module` have a kwarg boolean param called `training` . So instead of `teacher_training` we should simply use `training` param. This param is automatically set depending on your model training mode (`model.train()` and `model.eval()`).

Comment: `def forward(self, inputs, future=0, teacher_force_ratio=0.2, target=None, **kwargs):` and use `if self.train:` to define code to be run only while training. Is that correct?

Comment: It is `if self.training:`.